# Tokenize Function in Hive

Tags: hive, tokenize, tf-idf

I am trying to follow this example where the term frequency and inverse document frequency is calculated in Hive:https://github.com/myui/hivemall/wiki/TFIDF-calculation

I have a table called pigoutputhive where I have the following fields:

[image: Hive Schema]

The 'body' column contains a string of words [a-z A-Z & 0-9 only] separated by spaces.

I would like to tokenize the body so that I can generate a relation with a owneruserid and body tuple in order to perform the TF-IDF algorithm.

I am receiving an error relating the the tokenize function, can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

My error is as follows: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10011]: Line 8:37 Invalid function 'tokenize' [ERROR_STATUS]

```
create or replace view pigoutputhive_exploded
as
select
owneruserid, 
body,
score
from
pigoutputhive LATERAL VIEW explode(tokenize(body,true)) t as word
where
not is_stopword(word);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tokenize function is a Hivemall extension to Hive.

So, you need to install Hivemall first.

See the following page for loading Hivemall functions into Hive.
https://github.com/myui/hivemall/wiki/Installation

Answer (score 0):

Tokenize does not work in Hive and had to use sentences() function.